# Simple mod_rewrite issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a real weird issue

I'm playing around with .htaccess and trying to redirect all requests to the /test/ folder's index file.

My site lies in a folder /test/ in my local htdocs folder. No other files exist currenlty.

**What I expect:**
When I visit any url, (for example `/test/category/one/`) I should be redirected to `/test/index.php`

**What happens**
I get a `404 Not Found`

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php?__route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried setting `RewriteBase /test/`

This is as straight forward as it gets so why isn't it working?

I have a Wordpress site in another folder and that works flawlessly with custom rewrites.

I even copied the Wordpress' .htaccess contents to the test site's, substituting the rewrite base and last rule with /test/.

**Wordpress' .htaccess:** (which works on a seperate WP install on same server)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now and read quite a few SO articles with no help.

I even write a rewrite log file and now there shows nothing when I browse to the test site but a visit to the Wordpress site writes quite a few lines.

I am running XAMPP on a Win64 machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! =)

Comment: "It does not work" - great explanation of your problem, I'm contacting Charles Xavier to help me figure out what "does not work" means for you.

Comment: @hakra I apologize for not mentioning it. What 'does not work' is the rewrite rule does not get executed and I get a `404 Page Not Found` error. What should happen is for me to be redirected to the /test/index.php

Comment: `.` matches precisely one character, and there are no captured groups`. Try `(.+)`.

Comment: @arxanas It does not work either. Even the Wordpress redirect does not work for this site (which works on another site in another folder).

Comment: Does WordPress live one level above your *test* folder, or is it in a peer-level folder? If it's one level up, WordPress could be preventing this .htaccess from working properly...

Comment: is your rewrite_module actived ?

Comment: @JonahBishop, it is on the same level. They both lie in the root of /htdocs. So i have htdocs/test and htdocs/wordpress.

Comment: @Michel-F.Portzert, yes it is. It works for another site which uses it on the same server

Comment: Hey here's a thought, I just tried simulating your situation. Is it possible the htaccess file is actually named .htaccess.txt, due to Windows hiding file extensions? Right-click on the file and click Properties. This should show the "true" name of the file.

Comment: Nope. Just checked to make sure. It's definitely an htaccess file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: Also, make sure the line endings in your .htaccess file are set appropriately. Apache can sometimes choke on anything that doesn't include the new-line (\n) character.

So it looks to me like you want to (at some level) emulate what WordPress is doing. Here's how I handled this case when I was developing some software that did the same thing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For files that exist (i.e. either the `-f` or `-d` test passes), we serve them up unchanged. Otherwise, we redirect incoming requests to index.php. Note that the `/test` portion of the path is not included in the RewriteRule, since the RewriteBase set up where we were starting from. So, in your example, I think it would end up being:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?__route=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

FWIW, I'm no .htaccess expert. I've simply found this to work for me in the past.

Also, if you're on a shared host (like DreamHost), you may need to set up the appropriate rules for allowing default error documents. Some shared web hosts serve up a single file (failed_auth.html is one example) for error cases. If you're not filtering out that case, you may end up with a 404.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this is also not working. :( Even if it is an empty directory with just the .htaccess and index.php files. And another thing, if I copy and paste you example exactly I get a `Error 500` server error. But when I put a `#` on the first line it gives a `404 Not Found` error. This is also quite strange.

Comment: If the first line is giving you an error 500, then your web server is misconfigured somehow (i.e. mod_rewrite must be disabled). Take a look at your server logs for more information.

Comment: This is the error in the apache error log: `<IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules`

Comment: What I don't get is why it is working for the Wordpress site but not for the test site

Comment: What editor are you using to modify your .htaccess files? I've seen some comments on other sites that indicate that Apache apparently expects the line ending to be Linux-style (\n) not Windows style (\r\n). It might be worth running your .htaccess through `dos2unix` to see if that helps.

Comment: GENIUS!! I use Sublime Text 2 and I went to View->Line Endings and for some reason it was set to "Mac OS 9". I switched it to Unix, saved file and it works! Just for interests sake I changed it to "Windows" and it still worked. Thank you so much for all your help! Will you update your answer to reflect this and I'll accept it. Or I can just accept it anyway because your code is working. Just want anyone who stumbles upon this to see the correct solution :)

Comment: Actually your code is not working. I get redirected to the XAMPP root. But if I add `/test` to line 7 it works :)

Comment: I think the reason mine doesn't work is because there's a leading slash on line 7. If you change line 7 to `index.php` and not `/index.php` it should work.

Comment: Yeah, removing the leading slash on line 7 fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, just ran into this after deleting empty lines in my htaccess... apparently N++ was set to Mac line endings and Apache didn't like that. Fun.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
# Activate the rewrite module.
RewriteEngine On
# Ensure the requested URL is not a file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Ensure the requested URL is not a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?__route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank for your response but unfortunately this is also not working :(

Comment: This code is working now. Thanks again. It was a line endings issue. Just an FYI. See the comment of @Jonah's answer.